# SVN won't import *.a library

Tags: svn

I've got a compiled static library (with an "a" extension) I want to include in my SVN repository but adding it never works (no problems adding other types of items). If I change the extension (e.g., "library.a" --> "library.b"), the add works. Why is the "a" extension failing? Is there a way around this without renaming the file?

Comment: What does "svn status --no-ignore" tell you ? Does it see the *.a files ?

Comment: The I in front means the file is being ignored. Since the global is not ignoring you have a local ignore. do "svn propedit svn:ignore"

Comment: This was also discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125303/svn-propget-svnignore-returns-nothing-but-svn-is-obviously-ignoring-my-files/2125487#2125487

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Have you checked your global ignore settings. On linux they are stored in ~/.subversion/config

The default on my machine is :

```
global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo
```

so it ignores *.a files

more info [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3)

You should be able to add the file with

```
svn add "file" --no-ignore
```

to bypass any ignore rule set.

If the command:

```
svn status --no-ignore
```

returns with **I** in front you have a local Ignore. Run:

```
svn propedit svn:ignore
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm on Mac OS X and in my ~/.subversion/config file, the global-ignores is set to the default:

    `global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la #*# .*.rej *.rej .*~ *~ .#* .DS_Store`

which does not include *.a.

Comment: I'm on OS-X (10.8.latest) and my global-ignores is commented out, which I read to mean "no global-ignores."  Yet, whenever I add a directory with a library .a file (example: 3rd party libs, such as Flurry), it always skips the .a file.  Then my client can't build, then I go back and `svn add somelib.a` explicitly, then all is good.  Is there a way to **turn off** this default "skip all the .a-s" behaviour?  Thanks!

Comment: @Olie You must not comment the global-ignores out! Make sure that they are not commented out but remove the *.a from the list of ignored files then it will work.

Comment: Maybe its worth to add that - in TortoiseSVN - these global ignores can be found and editied in the TortoiseSVN settings itself (rightclick -> Settings/General)

Answer (score 4):

So, I suggest actually edit that ~/.subversion/config file to allow .a files again:

```
global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.pyc *.pyo
#global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo
```

Because I have a lot of those .a files in my projects.

Comment: I had to the very same thing w/1.7.  Even when commented out, SVN decided to global ignore files anyway.  Violation of the principle of least surprise for sure.  What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OSX (Lion) I'm using SCPlugin (http://scplugin.tigris.org/).

This adds a nice finder popup with SVN commands on it and it allows me to add *.a files when svnx or xcode don't allow it.

I suspect it's actually a bug as it's clearly ignoring the correct ignore settings (ironically), but for those who don't want to mess with terminal, it's proving handy.

EDIT: SmartSVN also allows you to see ignored files so they can be added as any normal file. Just check the 'ignored files' options under the view menu.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, if you're using SVN import (i.e., not a working copy), you can override the global ignores with:

```
--config-option=config:miscellany:global-ignores=[new ignores]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can add library on svn:

```
svn add library.a --no-ignore
```

After add svn need to be update:

```
svn update
```

Commit changes on svn using:

```
svn commit -m "library.a added on svn"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met this question recently, this is my way:

```
svn import --no-ignore --force  svn://destination
```